# Invoke-WebRequest forms authentication not working / ASP.Net_SessionID cookie missing

Tags: powershell, webrequest, powershell-4.0, asp.net-session

I have the below PowerShell script which aims to login to a website using forms authentication.
It seems that despite there being no errors / the returned status code always being 200, the script's not getting beyond the login page.
Doing some initial research using Fiddler I've found that a cookie, `ASP.Net_SessionId` is being created when the site's accessed via the browser, which does not exist when accessed via my script.

Any tips on what the issue may be, or how I can dig deeper into what's going on here?  Thank-you in advance.

```
#nb: site is configured to use forms auth

clear-host

#headers copied from my Fiddler session of the same interaction with Chrome; i.e. in case any of these settings are important...
$Headers = @{
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' = 1
    'Accept' = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
    'Accept-Encoding' = 'gzip, deflate, sdch'
    'Accept-Language' = 'en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,fr-FR;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2'
    #'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36' #this has its own parameter
}

$loginPage = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://example.com/login.aspx' -Method Get -SessionVariable loginSession -Headers $Headers -UserAgent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'

#code to see what's going on
    write-verbose "1. -------------------" -Verbose
    write-verbose $loginPage.StatusCode -Verbose       #returns 200
    write-verbose $loginPage.ParsedHtml.title -Verbose #returns 'log in'
    $loginSession | select *
    $loginPage.BaseResponse.Cookies | %{write-host "Cookie: $($_.Name)" -ForegroundColor Green} #shows a culture cookie, but no auth cookies
    write-verbose $loginSession -Verbose #session variable is corrected; nothing particularly interesting in this
#end of investigative code


#form auth
$loginForm = $loginPage.Forms['aspnetForm']
$loginForm.Fields['ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UsrLogin1_LoginView1_Login1_UserName'] = 'myUsername'
$loginForm.Fields['ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UsrLogin1_LoginView1_Login1_Password' ] = 'myPassword'
#comparing Fiddler Chrome session with PS session I found that PS had been sending additional buttons on the form / hadn't populated the hidden field; 
$loginForm.Fields.Remove('ctl00_ModalError_btnCancel')
$loginForm.Fields.Remove('ctl00_ModalError_btnConfirm')
$loginForm.Fields['ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField'] = ';;AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.60501.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={public key token removed form SO post}:en-GB:{long hex string removed form SO post}'

#$Headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' #this has its own parameter
#$Headers['Content-Length'] = #PS calculates this for us based on the body (confirmed with Fiddler), so no need for us to calculate here

<# attempts at other auth mechanisms; though checking IIS I can see that only forms auth is used / checking Fiddler these are clearly superfluous)
    #basic auth
    $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("myUsername:myPassword"))
    $Headers['Authorization'] = "Basic $encodedCreds"

    #creds
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('myUsername', (ConvertTo-SecureString 'myPassword' -AsPlainText -Force))
    $loginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://example.com/login.aspx' -Method Post -Body $loginForm.Fields -WebSession $loginSession -Headers $Headers -Credential $cred 
#>

#FYI: $loginForm.Action = login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPageOnceLoggedIn.aspx
$loginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "http://mySite/$($loginForm.Action)" -Method Post -Body $loginForm.Fields -WebSession $loginSession -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' #Fiddler shows that Chrome includes 2 cookies; the culture cookie and the ASP.NET_SessionId one; PS only has the culture cookie

#code to see what's going on
    write-verbose "2. -------------------" -Verbose
    write-verbose $loginResponse.StatusCode -Verbose #again, 200 (though fiddler shows there's a 302 here when accessed via Chrome)
    write-verbose $loginResponse.ParsedHtml.title -Verbose #again, still 'log in'
    $loginSession | select *
    $loginResponse.BaseResponse.Cookies | %{write-host "Cookie: $($_.Name)" -ForegroundColor Green} #still only the culture cookie
    write-verbose $loginSession -Verbose #same as before
#end of investigative code

$page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri  'http://example.com/PageOnceLoggedIn.aspx'-Method Get -WebSession $loginSession -Headers $Headers -Credential $cred 

#code to see what's going on
    write-verbose "3. -------------------" -Verbose
    write-verbose $page.StatusCode -Verbose #again, 200
    write-verbose $page.ParsedHtml.title -Verbose #again, 'log in'
    $loginSession | select *
    $page.BaseResponse.Cookies | %{write-host "Cookie: $($_.Name)" -ForegroundColor Green} #again, only culture
    write-verbose $loginSession -Verbose
#end of investigative code
```

Comment: I would send all required form fields when doing the login request, perhaps Viewstate, etc...? Everything that fiddler captures when doing a usual browser based login request.

Comment: I would also include the `_EVENTVALIDATION` field.

Comment: Thanks @Legends.  Sadly I'm posting `$loginForm.Fields`; which includes all fields on that form (though no `_EVENTVALITION` field exists).